# Overload error on Accumulator arg of reduce in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have below

```
const foo = (
  fields: {
    [key: string]: string,
  }
) => {
  const { one, two } = Object.values(fields).reduce(
    (acc, field) => {
      if (isOne(field)) {
        return { ...acc, two: [...acc.two, field] }
      }
      return { ...acc, one: [...acc.one, field] }
    },
    { one: [], two: [] }
  )

  // ...
}
```

But I keep getting an error about

```
Argument of type '(acc: { one: never[]; two: never[]; }
```

Comment: "Argument of type" _what_?

Comment: Can you post a link to a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html) that demonstrates your error? It's not easy to reconstruct this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you assign an object containing empty array literals to a variable, the compiler will tend to infer that those arrays are of type `never[]`, which is a fairly useless type:

```
const init = { one: [], two: [] };
/* const init: {
    one: never[];
    two: never[];
} */

init.one.push("whoops"); // error!
```

This is probably a design limitation of TypeScript, as per [microsoft/TypeScript#29398](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29398).  You might expect that the compiler would defer assigning a type to an empty array literal until it has more context for what the element types will be, but such deferred inference often has other side effects.

For now, I'd suggest that if the compiler infers a type you don't want for a particular value, you should [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#type-annotations) or [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) the type of that value instead:

```
const init2: { one: string[], two: string[] } = { one: [], two: [] };
init2.one.push("okay"); // okay
```

---

For the `reduce()` code you have here, the compiler infers that the accumulator is of type `{one: never[], two: never[]}`.  It can't reconcile that with the return type of the reducer callback (something like `{one: string[], two: never[]} | {one: never[], two: string[]}`) and so it gives up on that call signature.  Since `reduce()` is an overloaded function and the compiler can't match your call to any of the call signatures, you get an error about overloaded functions.

Again, the right thing to do here is to tell the compiler that the initial value of your accumulator is of type `{one: string[], two: string[]}`. The easiest way to do this is to [explicitly specify the generic type parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#hello-world-of-generics) in the `reduce()` call:

```
const { one, two } = Object.values(fields).
  reduce<{ one: string[], two: string[] }>( // <-- specify here
    (acc, field) => {
      if (isOne(field)) {
        return { ...acc, two: [...acc.two, field] }
      }
      return { ...acc, one: [...acc.one, field] }
    },
    { one: [], two: [] }
  )
```

Now there's no error: if the accumulator is typed as `{one: string[], two: string[]}`, the call to `reduce()` works because the callback is inferred to return a value of the same type, as required.

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMBWEFgMID2IAzmFAK64FTIDeAUMsgG5wA25ExAPACoB8ACgIAuOsgDaxMaSigA5gF0xvZAF9kAH2QBBKFDgBPADLAA1hD78AlComKA3IxbtOxYWNprbyOCEP2Tmr0IfQAJjhscFAoMOQguMBEyMDEqCAQggAeMmQKPugEBGwQfk70CESkKSDAYMgAvOJEEGL2ADTIYADuopKK6k4A9ABUyJUk9aB1nsjOTC1iGczQgfNdvUsQK1BrGiNDIdNgAHQtJwAO5MQAFoIARN03RRfE99YOyENDyNBQ1ABCEITarHABMs0WyFkCg6Gz6MJA8ns6kazQybUUnR6fRRaic4LOGUu1zu9wIZiM70+32QFKMwKq9RgRTRgmcMGAEDYYWkdHWEgshlyciRymheSR7WcwWsjX4-KYIPqtDpGWxvVRTQw2FwJ1YHC4gk53N51hO6xiYUollVUMRyKx8JFsIGaiEXx+3AAtN7oRccMAYIZkDdoBB1kxBIgEJ0TTy5Q0FQwmKnU0HkIJUulMvGwtY5Sm08WYmByFAQOITtWYxrcdWTjGTji41yeW7I6ngsXU6Xy5XVQ3a2rWpIhwgEESIK3TR2e2ppT27Rj+nXMep1tYQkxaQ36GogA)